# Laravel Request / Validation always return string type values

Tags: laravel

In laravel 7, the `$request->all()` or the `$validator->valid()`, always return an array of values, key assign is correct, but the values are always strings.

I need the validator to transform the field to the rules i made.

Example in rules for validation : `['no' => 'required|integer|min:1',...]`

Example of the output of validation->valid() : `[ "no" => "1231" ]` - string typed, i need this to be integer like : `[ "no" => 1231 ]`

I dont want to cast every field one by one... what i'm doing wrong ?

*NOTE*
All the validations works well, it's only the output of the fields that i want to match the validation, if i say the field is integer, the result of the validation must be integer and not string.

Comment: `no filed must be interger` you got this error?

Comment: nope, allready tried numeric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve this problem :
Create a FormRequest file, and put the validations, rules and messages there.
I dont know why... in the last version : my validations , rules and messages stay in the controller file.

Clear cache, everything ok.

Comment: Whether the validation rules are in a separate class or not would make no difference. The values are submitted via HTTP as strings, and remain so. Model attribute casting is the only thing that changes their type.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid repetitive type coercion, use this package for Laravel:

https://github.com/qtlenh/laravel-strict-validator

Input data will be automatically type-coerced during validation:

```
['no' => 'integer:cast']
```